# Handlebars js access one element from nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a nodejs application. I'm using handlebars js as a view engine. I'm trying to access one element from nested object that I'm passing to the hbs view.

```
router.get('/view_users/:id', function (req, res, next) {
Users.find({ userId: req.params.id }, function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        res.render('view_user', { title: 'Users', user: users});
    }
})
```

});

and then in the view_user I would like to access only one users.name.`<p>{{users.name}}</p>` (Without built-in helpers such as #each because it will return me a list of all users)

I tried `{{user.name}}`, `{{name}}`, and {{{user.name}}} but it returns me undefined.

Users is the mongoose Schema.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Does `{{title}}` work?

Comment: Yes it works fine

Comment: I believe the problem with the users object

Comment: Well it look like so yes. Can you do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(users));` right before your call to the `render` method?

Comment: It  prints the object[{"_id":"586abcad062b2b1254bb5303","name":"Test3423","description":"","departmen
tName":"Test3","__v":0,"departmentId":["5864345ef7834d3fc07d8d6c"]}]

Comment: router.get('/view_users/:id', function (req, res, next) {
Users.find({ userId: req.params.id }, function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        res.render('view_user', { title: 'Users', user: JSON.stringify(users)});
    }
})
Still prints nothing when I do {{user.name}} in the view_users hbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` method will return a list of documents. That's why you get 
(from your comment above): `object[{"_id":"586abcad062b2b1254bb5303","name":"Test3423","‌​description":"","dep‌​artmen tName":"Test3","__v":0,"departmentId":["5864345ef7834d3fc07d‌​8d6c"]}]`. This is an array with you model inside.

Use instead `findOne` method, it will return directly the User document. You make your request using userId, so you will always get the good document.

You can read more from the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

> Anywhere a callback is passed to a query in Mongoose, the callback follows the pattern `callback(error, results)`. What results is depends on the operation: For `findOne()` it is a potentially-null single document, `find()` a list of documents, `count()` the number of documents, `update()` the number of documents affected, etc. The API docs for Models provide more detail on what is passed to the callbacks.

Another solution is to get the first element of the users array:

```
res.render('view_user', { title: 'Users', user: users[0] });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Use findOne if you want to search for a particular user it will provide a user object. where find will return an array of users/user.

try this:

```
router.get('/view_users/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Users.findOne({ userId: req.params.id }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.render('view_user', { title: 'Users', user: user });
        }
    })
})
```

Or

use the first element of the array if you have only one user (not recommended for multiple user sets).

```
res.render('view_user', { title: 'Users', user: users[0]});
```

Or

Iterate in view (recommended for multiple users list)

```
   {{#each this}}
        {{name}}
    {{/each}}
```

Here's a simplified fiddle to show what I'm asking: http://jsfiddle.net/KPCh4/2/

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wonder why you can't directly reference a property in an object with Handelbars. `Users.findOne()` returns a single user object, like `{name: "John", email: "john@example.com"}`.  In the view, it seems you can only access it via the `{{#each}}` iterator, rather than directly with `{{user.name}}`.